# Find the first path in a grid from top left to bottom right using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to move from the upper left corner to the bottom right corner of a grid using recursion. However, at each point in time, I can only move up, down, left, or right exactly the number of squares given by the number I'm standing on.

For example, if you were standing on a 3, I could move exactly three squares left, three squares right, three squares up, or three squares down. I can't move off the board.

[image]

I have tried looking for a starting point but I'm blank. Can someone help?

```java
        public int traverse(int[][] grid, int size, int x, int y){

            // base condition
            if(x == size-1 & y == size-1)
                return 0;

            // value of current square
            int square = grid[y][x];

            // move right
            if(x + square < size)
                return square + traverse(grid, size, x + square, y);

            // move down
            if(y + square < size)
                return square + traverse(grid, size, x, y + square);

            // move left
            if(x - square > -1)
                return square + traverse(grid, size, x - square, y);

            // move up
            if(y - square > -1)
                return square + traverse(grid, size, x, y - square);

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to calculate all paths, or calculate the shortest path, or anything else? How are the squares numbered?

Comment: Show the code that you have so far.

Comment: I am want to calculate a single path, if possible. and the squares random values from 1-n where 0<n<10 @AbhinavMathur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a DFS for the task, that tracks the current visited path as well. Here's a simple Python implementation, which can be easily optimized and implemented in other languages.

```py
def dfs(i, j, matrix, visited, path):
    # check if current point if out of bounds
    if i < 0 or i> len(matrix):
        return []
    if j < 0 or j> len(matrix[0]):
        return []
    
    # check if current point has been visited earlier
    if visited.get((i,j)):
        return visited[(i,j)]

    # add current point to path
    new_path = path + [(i,j)]

    # check if we've reached bottom right point
    if i==len(matrix)-1 and j == len(matrix[0])-1:
        return new_path
    
    # so that dfs doesn't get stuck in infinite recursion for cycles
    visited[(i,j)] = []

    value = matrix[i][j]
    possible_paths = [
        dfs(i+value,j,matrix,visited,new_path),
        dfs(i-value,j,matrix,visited,new_path),
        dfs(i,j+value,matrix,visited,new_path),
        dfs(i,j-value,matrix,visited,new_path)
    ]

    for option in possible_paths:
        if option:
            # we have found a path
            visited[(i,j)] = option
            return option
    
    #no path found
    return []
```

Comment: Iaw with the SO help, try to avoid giving students complete answers to homework. Everyone benefits more if an answer includes only enough to get OP past the the current block to their learning. (I have been guilty of giving too much info myself and realized later that this was bad.)

Comment: @Gene good suggestion, thanks